# How to close Microsoft Edge Download Pop up or their notification

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

[image]

[image]

I am using selenium to switch windows but I am trying to close these 2 as they pop up when it is in automation mode and it screws up the window_handles. Is there a way to stop them from showing up other than using headless mode.

I have tried using all these commands but the notifications/pop up are still showing.

```
        self.edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        self.prefs = {
        'download.default_directory': str(self.temp_path),
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # Disable download prompt
        "download.directory_upgrade": True
                  }
        self.edge_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', self.prefs)
        self.edge_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        self.edge_options.add_argument("--no-download-notification")
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first popup looks like Edge personalize prompt, you can disable the prompt and Edge download popup using the code below:

```
prefs = {
   'browser':{
      'show_hub_popup_on_download_start': False
  },
   'user_experience_metrics':{
      'personalization_data_consent_enabled': True
  }
}
edge_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already attempted to disable notifications with --disable-notifications and --no-download-notification, some websites may still manage to display pop-ups.You can try additional steps:

1. Disable Pop-ups:
   self.edge_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
2. Disable Infobars:
   self.edge_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
3. Disable Extensions:
   self.edge_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
4. Use Specific Profile:
   self.edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/profile")
   You can create a separate user profile to store your preferences.Remember to experiment with these options one at a time or in combination to find the most effective solution for your specific case.